# List all python3 class properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

**Edit:** The methods below work when using the class, but not working when using an instance. They work in Python3 also.

```
class A:
    @property
    def p(self):
        return ""

>>> a = A()
>>> vars(a)
{}
>>> vars(A)
{'p': <property object at 0x0000000000000000>, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>>
```

==================================================

I'm looking for a method to list all properties defined with a `@property` decorator (and those only) in a class in python3.

In python2, you could use `vars` and get all the attributes which are an instance of the `property` class (as mentioned in many previous answers), but in python3 it doesn't work this way and `vars` doesn't return the properties. Using `__dict__` is the same as using `vars`.

Using `dir()` return all the attributes, and doesn't let to distinguish between properties and other attributes.

In addition, when accessing the property, it has the type of the returned value, and it's not an instance of `property`.

My final goal is to define my own type of properties (by inheriting `property`), and list the properties from each type.

Comment: instance.__dict__ that return all property, but not the type.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @JacopoBonomi using `__dict__` is the same as using `vars`. It doesn't return the properties defined with a `@property` decorator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility to list all property instances of a class:

**the `dir` way**

```
class A():
    def __init__(self): pass
    @property
    def c(self): return self._c
    @c.setter
    def c(self, v): self._c = v

    @property
    def d(self): return self._c
    @c.setter
    def d(self, v): self._c = v

props =  = filter(lambda attr: isinstance(v, property), [getattr(A, i) for i in dir(A)])

print(list(props))
```

Output

```
[<property object at 0x7fee3a1470e0>, <property object at 0x7fee3a147130>]
```

**the `__dict__`way**

```
props = {k: v for k, v in A.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, property)}
print(list(props))
```

Output

```
{'c': <property object at 0x7efd84c21090>, 'd': <property object at 0x7efd84c210e0>}
```

The `__dict__`way has the advantage to keep reference of the property identifier

Comment: The "In addition" part is not clear to me. An example would be useful

Comment: It seems that you need to use `vars` with the class and not an instance of the class, that what was not working for me. Thanks!

Comment: answer edited following the above comment

Comment: I saw — have upvoted following the edit :)

Comment: Notice that `vars` and `__dict__` gives the same result - should add it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example in the interactive REPL that will demonstrate how to do this:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   @property
...   def bar(self):
...     return self
...     
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
<__main__.Foo object at 0x11b197828>
>>> Foo.bar
<property object at 0x11b677548>
>>> f.__class__.__dict__['bar']
<property object at 0x11b677548>
>>> vars(f)
{}
>>> vars(Foo)
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'bar': <property object at 0x11b677548>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> vars(Foo) == Foo.__dict__
True
>>> type(f) is f.__class__ is Foo
True
>>> {k:v for k, v in vars(Foo).items() if isinstance(v, property)}
{'bar': <property object at 0x11b677548>}
>>> {k:v for k, v in vars(type(f)).items() if isinstance(v, property)}
{'bar': <property object at 0x11b677548>}
>>> dir(Foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'bar']
>>> dir(f)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'bar']
>>> [d for d in dir(f) if isinstance(getattr(f, d), property)]
[]
>>> [d for d in dir(Foo) if isinstance(getattr(Foo, d), property)]
['bar']
```